# How to use commas around 'well'

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, sentence

In the sentence:

"He needs it to, well, do it"

as if spoken words, are the commas correct? I'm trying to break up the sentence as you would when speaking, but I'm not sure if I only need the second comma.

Comment: I've seen ellipsis used for this:  "He needs to... well... do it." (or "to... well, do it")

Comment: It's parenthetical. Of the typical choices for offsetting punctuation, zero punctuation isn't an option here. Nor is a pair of brackets.   I'd probably choose a pair of dashes, giving an abruptness intermediate between the choice of comma and ellipsis. I might  also italicise 'well', in this case to signal downtoning,  adding to the hint of persuading.